# Wiring light switches in two rooms help

Tags: wiring

I am changing some wiring in two rooms of my house. Room 1 had two switches that controlled an outlet. We have since taken one of those switches and installed a ceiling light. The other switch controls an outlet now (this is the one I want to work on). I want to make the outlet always hot and delete the switch. I attached a picture of the switch. What do I tie together and what do I cap off? There's 2 sets of wires coming in. White from A is top of the switch. Black from B is bottom of switch. Red from A is top left of switch. Black from A is tied to white from B. [image]

Room 2 has a switch that controls an outlet. It is the only switch in the room that does this. I will be switching the switch out to a double switch and putting in two separate sets on lights (one set of recessed and another light). Again, I want to make the outlet always hot and have the switches control the sets of lights independent (one switch for recessed one for the other). How can I wire this? Current switch has two sets of wires coming in. Wire A and B have the blacks tied together and a pigtail to the top of the switch. Wire A and B have the whites tied together. Wire B has a red attached to the bottom of the switch. [image]

Edit - picture of the second switch for room 1 that was asked for. The right switch is for this room. The left switch is for a completely different room. It has the new wire to the ceiling light (yellow sheath). Black from there goes to switch. Black and red from an old wire is wirenut together and pigtail to bottom of switch. White is nutted with 2 other old whites (3 total) [image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the other switch box in room 1 please?

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: Is the existing wire 12AWG or 14AWG?

Comment: New wire is 12. Old wire appears to be the same thickness but I don't see any markings

Comment: It sure looks like you've got a damaged cable in the first picture.  See the exposed copper?

Comment: That added picture is fairly difficult to see what is going on.  Any chance you can push some wires around to make it clearer what goes where?

Comment: I agree with @Harper, make sure you investigate the exposed copper (damaged cable/NM/Romex) in the first photo.

Comment: Do you have a non-contact voltage tester?   This device, sometimes called a "hot stick", will show you which wires are "hot" from upstream and which wires go downstream.   You can also use an AC voltmeter.   Work safely!